# Formula to import multiple columns to 1 column if a name from a different list matches any name in those columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Looking for a way to import a long range of columns in to 1 list if a name from a different list matches any name in that particular column.  I've tried a couple variations of query, filter, vlookup... Can't seem to find the right combination.  Example..

List A on sheet 1 contains the names Jim, John and James.  On a separate sheet, there are 5 columns containing names.  Column 1 contains Jim, Alex and Ben.  Column 2 contains Harold, Bob and Jimmy.  Column 3 contains James, Jeremy and Felix.  Column 4 contains James, Eric and Evan.  Column 5 contains Sara, Jamie and Xavier.  The end result should display the list in 1 column to contain the names - Jim, John, James, Alex, Ben, Jeremy, Felix, Eric and Evan. Columns 1, 3 and 4 would be imported to a single list because at least 1 name within those columns matched a name in the original list.

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EyeeyseRhCsqNMUTz0FOAFsRdsBiLb8I9jJWxTi14Sc/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ***UPDATED***

You can try this sample implementation below using Apps Script custom function. Just copy and paste it to your spreadsheet file as a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script):

> ***NOTE:*** This script will check each name listed on the "**Main List**" & if each of them has matches on multiple columns on the second sheet ***Sheet2***, then it will place all of the names on columns that contains any matched name on the "**Imported List**". The only catch using this implementation is that it'll run a bit slow when there's a huge amount of data to be processed.

### SCRIPT

```
function onOpen(){ //Runs every time you open the spreadsheet
   FINDMATCH();
}

function onEdit(){//Runs every time you make an edit to the sheet
   FINDMATCH();
}

function FINDMATCH() { //Function to check each columns on "Sheet2" to see if it has names that match any names on the "Main List"
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var mainList = [].concat.apply([], main.getRange("A4:A").getValues()).filter(String); //Main list data starts at A4
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet2"); //Name of the Sheet2
  var result = mainList;
  for(col=1; col <= sheet2.getDataRange().getLastColumn(); col++){
    // E.G. if you only want to set the maximum of 2 rows as seen below, the "currentCol" code will only scan range A1:F3 on Sheet2 because the number 3 on the third parameter of the getRange() method will be the maximum row to be scanned.
    var currentCol = [].concat.apply([], sheet2.getRange(1,col,2,1).getValues()).filter(String);
    mainList.forEach(function(list){
      currentCol.forEach(function(data){
        if(data == list){
          result.push(currentCol.toString());
          return;
        }
      });
    });
  }
  var data = FILTER(result.toString().trim().split(","));
  main.getRange("AG4:AG").clearContent(); //Clears the old "Imported List" data before pasting updated list of names
  main.getRange(4,33,data.length,1).setValues(data); //Updates the "Imported List"
}

function FILTER(array) { //Function that filters duplicate names
  var data = array;
  var newData = [];
  var formattedData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row === newData[j] && row === newData[j]) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  newData.forEach(function(i){
    formattedData.push([i]);
  });
  return formattedData;
}
```

### Sample Result:

> **Sample Sheet**

[image]

> **When spreadsheet gets updated with new data**

[image]

[image]

Comment: While that works for manually checking and having to update that formula every time, I'm looking for a set it and forget it method.  The "main list" will change frequently, and I want something that will check a fairly large range of columns against the "main list" and import the columns where a match is found in the main list.  Unique will just list unique names found in the columns, and that isn't the goal I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @anonimoose
Got you. It looks it is quite infeasible to use solely the pre-loaded functions on Google Sheet with when it comes to "checking a fairly large range of columns against the "main list" & import the columns where a match is found in the main list" as looping through multiple columns would be impossible with these. This is quite a complex logic & I believe an Apps Script would be more ideal for this process, given that you're looking for a "set it and forget it method". I have updated my answer with an Apps Script implementation & hopefully it'll help you with your goal.

Comment: Looks promising! I'll give this a try today. Am I able to remove the update on edit function and everything still work fine? The sheet in question is used by many and already is a bit slow with how many conditionals and tabs are on it.

Comment: Can this be reconfigured to specify a maximum row to search for duplicates in sheet2?  There is other information below the lists that includes names that will also get picked up if the rows are left unlimited.

Comment: If you remove the onEdit() function , yes it will still work since onOpen() will still kick in but it will only auto-run the FINDMATCH function every time the spreadsheet gets reopened/reloaded from the browser. I have edited my code and added some comments on the FINDMATCH function, specifically on the line before the "var currentCol ..." for setting up maximum row to be scanned.

Comment: Excellent.  My last quirk.. Maybe I'm doing something wrong... but when I use this, it outputs the data to column B, even though I've changed `main.getRange("B4:B").clearContent();` to AG4:AG.  Am I missing the place to tell it where to output?

Comment: @anonimoose Glad to know it works. I have edited my answer again to set the 
 imported list on to the AG column. After the main.getRange("AG4:AG").clearContent(); line, I've replaced the current code main.getRange(4,2,data.length,1).setValues(data) with: main.getRange(4,33,data.length,1).setValues(data); (the second param is number 33, which is the column number of the AG column).

Comment: Also, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: just as a side note, the number of columns currently goes all the way to DS that it parses, so i removed the written triggers and added one via the script triggers menu for once a day between 5 and 6am which should be sufficient.  Thanks again for all your help, this seems to work perfectly.